# Updating chart.js with JSON from Razor page

Tags: c#, json, .net, chart.js

I have a chart.js in my Razor page displaying some data, but when I try to add an aditional dataset to the chart with an AJAX call i get an error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'data' on string '{"data":[{"x":"2020-01-11","y":12},{"x":"2020-01-12","y":100},{"x":"2020-01-13","y":2},{"x":"2020-01-14","y":122},{"x":"2020-01-16","y":20},{"x":"2020-01-19","y":2}],"label":"PRA Prime US100 M3","borderWidth":1,"borderColor":"rgba(255,99,132,1)","backgroundColor":"rgba(255,99,132,1)"}'
```

This is my chart, that renders fine with the included dataset:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        hour: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00',
                        day: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                        week: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                        month: 'MMM YYYY',
                        quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Test',
                data: [{
                    x: '2015-03-15',
                    y: 12
                },
                {
                    x: '2015-03-25',
                    y: 21
                },
                {
                    x: '2015-04-25',
                    y: 32
                },
                {
                    x: '2019-05-28',
                    y: 21
                }],
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            }]
    }
});
```

This is the AJAX function that gets a new dataset in JSON from the C# code and tries to insert it to the chart:

```
function algoCBChecked(checkbox) {
    var sName = checkbox.id;

    var run = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { sName: sName },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/index?handler=AlgoCBChecked',
        success: function (res) {
            addDataToChart(res);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert("An error occered, " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

function addDataToChart(data) {
    myChart.data.datasets.push(data);
    myChart.update();
}
```

This is the C# code that is called from AJAX and that returns the new dataset in JSon format:

```
public IActionResult OnGetAlgoCBChecked(string sName)
        {
            chartDataset ds = new chartDataset();
            ds.label = sName;
            ds.borderWidth = 1;
            ds.borderColor = "rgba(255,99,132,1)";
            ds.backgroundColor= "rgba(255,99,132,1)";
            ds.data.Add(new chartData { x = "2020-01-11", y = 12 });
            ds.data.Add(new chartData { x = "2020-01-12", y = 100 });
            ds.data.Add(new chartData { x = "2020-01-13", y = 2 });
            ds.data.Add(new chartData { x = "2020-01-14", y = 122 });
            ds.data.Add(new chartData { x = "2020-01-16", y = 20 });
            ds.data.Add(new chartData { x = "2020-01-19", y = 2 });

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);

            return new JsonResult(json);
        }
```

And finally this is the chartDataset and chartData classes:

```
public class chartData
    {
        public string x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
    }

    public class chartDataset
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public List<chartData> data = new List<chartData>();
        public int borderWidth { get; set; }
        public string borderColor { get; set; }
        public string backgroundColor { get; set; }
    }
```

I can see that the JSON is passed over to the addDataToChart function, but it cannot be added to the chart. Is my JSON formatting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[JsonResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0) "formats the given result as JSON."

By giving it a JSON string, you end up sending a double-serialized value to the browser. So even after jQuery deserializes it, you still end up with a string rather than an object.

So rather than passing `JsonResult` the serialized string representation, just give it the object you want to have serialized.

```
return new JsonResult(ds);
```